Can slack bot read bookmarks without joining the channel
I am trying to make my bot to read the channel bookmarks that it is not joining to see who's oncall right now. However, it is returning not_in_channel error.
Wondering if there's any permission I need to add to my bot to support that or this is currently not doable in slack api?

You'll need to add the bot to the channel with conversations.join first which will require the channels:join scope.
